# Did I get free gas?

Tags: knowledge, lateral-thinking

I was sitting at home one day when I felt a strong hunger overtake me. So I grab my keys and hop in the car. A quick glance at my gas gauge showed I had exactly half a tank. I drive a few miles over to the local burger shop, park, and head inside.

After I finished dining, I once again hop in my car to head home. After putting my keys in, I notice I now have a hair over half a tank of fuel.

How did I end up with more gas than I started with?

> It sure wasn't the burgers.

Comment: I don't think this is lateral thinking; fuel gauges are notoriously inaccurate

Comment: @Matt - Yes, that's true - but not in the particular way described. Without some particular set of conditions obtaining (see my answer for the most obvious), the gas level will not increase or appear to increase without actually adding fuel.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Your answer only applies the knowledge of fuel level sensors. I don't see any sideways thinking there

Comment: @Matt - The [tag:lateral-thinking] comes in when you have to come up with reasons for the anomalous readings.

Comment: I feel like it should be replaced with the situation tag...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> When your car was parked at home, it was parked on a hill such that the fuel tank was tilted to move the fuel away from the fuel level sensor.  When your car was parked at the burger barn, it was less tilted, or possibly tilted in the opposite direction.

Comment: Yep. Question was inspired by real life events.